# form submission on product detail page

Tags: php, mysql

I have following code on the top of product detail page

```
<?php
    include("include/connection.php");
    session_start();
    $ses_id = session_id();
    $ID = (int)$_REQUEST['id'];     

    if (!isset ($_POST['submit']))
    {
?>

<div class="row">
    <div class="span9">
        <div class="span6 ">
            <h4>Review(0)</h4>
            <p>There are no review for this product</p>
            <h4>Write a Review</h4>
        <form method="POST" action="<?php echo $_SERVER['PHP_SELF'];?>">
                <p>Your Name:</p>
                <input type="text" id="txtname" name="Rname" placeholder="write your name..." />
            <p>Your Review</p>
                Excelent<input type="radio" name="reviewbtn" class="radio" value="Excelent" />
            Good<input type="radio" class="radio" name="reviewbtn" value="Good" />
            Poor<input type="radio" class="radio" name="reviewbtn" value="Poor" /><br/>
                <textarea id="txtreview" name="txtbx" cols="50" rows="10" 
                            class="container-fluid"></textarea>
                <input type="submit" value="submit" class="btn" />
            </form>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>

<?php
    } else { 
        $Rname = mysql_real_escape_string(stripslashes(htmlentities($_POST["Rname"])));
        $Reviewbtn  = $_POST["reviewbtn"];
        $Txtbox= mysql_real_escape_string(stripslashes(htmlentities($_POST["txtbx"])));

        $sql=mysql_query ("INSERT INTO reviews (Name, Comments,Rating) VALUES('$Rname','$Reviewbtn','$Txtbox')", $con) or die (mysql_error());

        echo "Record added succesfully. You will be redirected to previous page in 5 seconds";
        header( "refresh:5;url= product_detail.php" );
    }
    mysql_close($con);
?>
```

here I am getting error

> Notice: Undefined index: id in \product_detail.php on line 5

( which is `$ID = (int)$_REQUEST['id'];` )

basically I am building a rating form on a product,please if someone can modify the code so form submission could be done using ajax jquery call so page should not load again

Answer (score 4):

remove int from it there no need of it.

```
$ID = $_REQUEST['id'];
```

Comment: it does not fixed the error. int is used that only integer value should be passed to avoid sql injection

Comment: try $_POST['id'] it might help you

Answer (score 1):

There is no Element named ID in your form

So when you are going to catch this it occurred error

```
 $ID = $_REQUEST['id']; 
                   ^ provide actual form element's name here
```

When you coming to this page from previous page it is not showing error

after submitting from it is showing error.

If it is, add an hidden element into your form

```
<input type='hidden' name='id' value="<?php echo $ID; ?>">
```

It will solve the problem

Comment: i think this will not work as $_REQUEST['id'] is coming from the previous page.and this page shows the detail of the product against that id

Comment: @MirzaSahaib: Answer eddited as you saying. try it now

Comment: now its not showing error but when i click on submit only pages refreshes and nothing happen mean data is not inserted in database

Answer (score 0):

Use some other word as  `name` attribute rather than naming it as `id` you can set it to `user_id` or something else you want,because it is not a good practice

```
if(isset($_REQUEST['user_id'])){
    $ID = $_REQUEST['user_id'];
    }
```